# Proving an upper set is the union of rays

Tags: real-analysis

$(DEF):$ Let $X$ be a totally ordered set. A set $A \subset X$ is called an upper set if $a \in A $ and $x > a $ implies $x \in A $.

$(PROBLEM):$ An upper set can be presented as a union or rays:

#### Attempt:

Let $A$ be an upper set. I want to show that $A = \bigcup_{a \in A}[a, \infty) $.

If $x \in \bigcup_{a \in A} [a, \infty) $, then $x \geq a $ and $a \in A $. By definition, we have $x \in A $.

Conversely, if $x \in A$ This means that for any $a \in A$ we have $x > a$ and so $x \in \bigcup_{a \in A} [a, \infty) $

Is this correct?

Comment: Willie Rosario: I noticed you have put another question on rays (open rays for that). Did you get a chance to look over my answer below for this question here, about your proof for upper sets being unions of rays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \in A$ and we also *assume* that there is a particular $a \in A$ for which $x>a,$ then the definition of upper set would imply that $x\in A.$ But this is a somewhat useless fact since we have already assumed $x \in A.$

So (in my opinion) your argument for the converse part needs work. How does your argument show there is a particular $a \in A$ for which $x>a$? [I agree that if this is shown then one can say that $x \in [a, \infty)$ hence in the union you are looking at.

*Added:* Maybe you're making it too involved. In the converse, you are assuming $x \in A.$ But then immediately you have since $x \in [x, \infty)$ that $x$ lies in one of the intervals of the form $[a, \infty)$ which your union is composed of.